# High-Frequency Circuits with commonly available parts

Tags: hf

Does radio shack carry any good chips or transistors for building high-frequency amps, oscillators, or mixers?

My friend and I are trying to build the coolest circuits possible with only Radio Shack stuff. He's built lots of 555 circuits, which of course are cool, but I think I could beat him at HF design. I've looked at some datasheets for some of the op-amps they have (maybe 741, I forget the exact number), and the frequency response of those chips falls off drastically at higher frequencies.

Comment: The automatic answer for any question starting "Does radio shack..." is, or should be, "NO!" ;)

Comment: true dat - but I was hoping someone, somewhere, knew how to hack the system that has forced me to order online anything circuit-related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not, but with limitations. A simplest that comes to my mind is FM transmitter as below:

[image: Schematic]

It won't be that stable, but ok for hobby purpose. You can get a lot of these stuff on the www.

Comment: lots of stuff available on the web, but I should have clarified - for reasons unknown to either of us, we've prohibited each other from using anything not found at Radio Shack or the hardware store